# PHP syntax error trying to build array within while loop with mysql resultset

Tags: php

Why do I get an unexpected ']' error on the $columnArray[]... line?

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","test");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))  { echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();}

 $sql = "SELECT column_comment,column_name FROM information_schema.columns  
  WHERE table_name = 'mytable'; 
 $query = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysql_error());
 $columnArray = array();

 $columnArray = array();

 while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){


   $columnArray[] = array('column_comment' => $result['column_comment'], 'column_name' => $result['column_name']);

 }
```

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Comment: Preview your question before pressing the submit button. If you wait some seconds, you see syntax highlighting getting active on your code-blocks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo, some missing quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even StackOverflow's syntax highlighting shows that you got your code broken. You need to close query string, so instead of:

```
$sql = "SELECT column_comment,column_name FROM information_schema.columns 
        WHERE table_name = 'mytable';
```

you need:

```
$sql = "SELECT column_comment,column_name FROM information_schema.columns  
        WHERE table_name = 'mytable'";
```

Get yourself something better than Notepad :)

Comment: I noticed the syntax highlighting thing myself before any answers, was ready to delete the question :(. There are more errors when I fix this, but I'm going to think about things properly before posting again! I was just thinking if only I wasn't using notepad.. Unfortunately I must persist. I work on a terminal that does not permit any further software being installed.

Comment: @pedromillers There are plenty of text editors that highlight your code for you. Try [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) for example.

Comment: @pedromillers terminal is one thing, editor is another. I recommend `vim`. If you are using it, then simple `:syntax on` should make you happier

Comment: by terminal I meant.. PC. It is on a network and we are blocked from running any installation files. VIM requires running an exe to install which I would not be able to.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax highlighting shows you the error. You're missing a closing quote:

```
 $sql = "SELECT column_comment,column_name FROM information_schema.columns  
  WHERE table_name = 'mytable';
```

should be

```
 $sql = "SELECT column_comment,column_name FROM information_schema.columns  
  WHERE table_name = 'mytable'";
```

Answer (score 1):

replace old query with this..

```
 $sql = "SELECT column_comment,column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'mytable'";
```